# How do I get newlines in a tweet?

Tags: twitter

Is there a reliable way to make newlines appear in a tweet?

The twitter website accepts them in the "Compose new tweet" box, but they don't show up in the stream.

The server receives them and stores them. When I look at the JSON the website receives, they are still there.

Some clients obviously manage to get newlines right, I've seen tweets (even on the website) that contain them.

So… what can I do to produce them myself?

Comment: Can you give us a link to a tweet that you saw having the new line on twitter's site?! Because I think it's up to the client to actually show that, but I don't think that they are showing new lines on the official site..

Comment: @Lipis Not right now. Maybe I remember it from the "old" Website? I've not seen any for a while, I must admit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no convention for storing newlines in the API and as such there is no reliable way to make newlines appear in all Twitter clients.

New lines do not appear in <s>all</s> most official clients

- Mobile, Web, iOS

There used to be a point in which it is was somewhat supported but this is no more.

Comment: Aww, this sucks. It's not that this would be a hard thing to implement. As I said, the very JSON they send over the wire still contains all newline characters. I am disappoint.

Comment: I'm sure there are a few clients that handle the line breaks, but they are in the minority.

Comment: Yeah. TweetBot does it, for example. But unless everybody can see it, it would be pointless anyway.

Comment: The official Mac client supports them.